# loop through update query pdo where id

Tags: mysql, pdo, foreach, while-loop, http-post

I am trying various ways to loop through a MySQL call procedure query (PDO)

In the following example I am updating **one column** in the table/database. The $_POST data submitted via a HTML table inside a form.

I plan to do a few other 'tabular data' forms and loop though MySQL call procedures with more than one column to be updated

All the update queries will be based on `WHERE ID = $id`

I have done something similar in school using a nested foreach loop, but I read somewhere that nested foreach loops should be avoided when posting data to mysql

- What is the best method in this situation with masses of tabular data
  to be updated via their primary key id?
- Is it ok to do massive looping through of MySql queries and if so
  which loops are best used here? While vs Foreach, For, Do, etc?.
- And then what is best here bindParam vs bindValue, placeholders ? vs 
  name etc?

---

```
/* Call up data based on some criteria while loop fetch it etc */

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) // Works and echoes some tabular data O.K

/* Snippet of the POST data concerned */
<td>
    <input type="text" name="allocate[]">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
</td>


/* Echoes something of the following HTML table inside form O.K */

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="allocate[]"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1244"></td>
    <td>echo stuff</td>
    <td>echo unrelated</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="allocate[]"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1255"></td>
    <td>echo stuff</td>
    <td>echo unrelated</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="allocate[]"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1399"></td>
    <td>echo stuff</td>
    <td>echo unrelated</td>
</tr>

/* The submitted form part */
<?php

$db = DBConn::getConnection(); // config files etc etc

if ( isset( $_POST['id'] ) && isset( $_POST['allocate'] )) {  // works

    // NOTE: no validation required for trusted "In-house" data entry 

    /* Simple method/varibles OR ?? */
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $allot = $_POST['allocate'];

    /* OR ?? implode and explode array etc etc version-method (execute(array(.. ?? */

    $id = explode(",",$_POST['id']);
    $allot = explode(",",$_POST['allocate']);

    /* The Update Query */

    //$sql = "UPDATE propertyStats SET allot = :allot WHERE ps_id = :ps_id";
    //$sql = "UPDATE propertyStats SET allot = ? WHERE ps_id = ?";

    $sql = 'CALL updatePropSat(?,?)'; // Call procedure tested & works OK in phpMyAdmin

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);


    /* executing in an array rather foreach loop method? */
    $stmt->execute(array($allot, $id));


    /* FOREACH ATTEMPT /* NOTE: Form HTML was different to above HTML example */

    foreach ($_POST['allocate'] as $ids => $value) {

        $sql = 'CALL updatePropSat(?,?)';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(1,  $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2,  $ids,   PDO::PARAM_INT);


        $stmt->execute();

        /* OR ALTERNATELY ?? */
        $stmt->execute(array($allot, $id));

    }

    /* WHILE LOOP ATTEMPT ( a flop I can few )*/

    $loopit = count($id); // did return correct number rows in the table/form

    $i = 0;
    while($i < $loopit) {

        $stmt->bindParam(':allot', $allot[$i]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ps_id', $id[$i]);

        $stmt->execute();

        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find all your questions are quite irrelevant.

The only problem I can extract from your question is a nested foreach loop. The only such loop I can think of is one updating columns of the same row not at once but one per query. This problem is irrelevant to PDO or whatever "best method". It's plain old SQL. You have to update all the columns for in the same row in one single query. Thus, you need no nested foreach to run your query in.

> which loops are best used here? While vs Foreach, For, Do, etc?.

Irrelevant. There are no "best loops".

> what is best here bindParam vs bindValue, placeholders ? vs name etc?

Irrelevant. They all the same.

> CALL updatePropSat(?,?)

Irrelevant. One don't need an SP to perform a simple update. Just run your update query using PDO

---

Now some hints.

For your single value populate your form like this

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="allocate[<?php=$ID?>]">
</td>
```

And you'll be able to loop over using the code from the other answer:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE propertyStats SET allot = ? WHERE ps_id = ?');
foreach ($_POST['allocate'] as $id => $value) {
    $stmt->execute(array($value, $id));
}
```

While for the multiple values that belong to the same row

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="data[<?php=$ID?>][allocate]">
    <input type="text" name="data[<?php=$ID?>][foo]">
    <input type="text" name="data[<?php=$ID?>][bar]">
    <input type="text" name="data[<?php=$ID?>][id]">
</td>
```

This way you'll be able to loop over your data most simple way

```
$sql = "UPDATE t SET allocate = :allocate, foo = :foo, bar = :bar WHERE id = :id";
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row)
{
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best method in this situation with masses of tabular data to be updated via their primary key id?

Prepared statement. The important part is to prepare them **once** outside the loop and then execute them **inside** the loop. In your exemple, you are preparing it inside the loop, which defeats the purpose:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('CALL updatePropSat(?,?)');
foreach ($_POST['allocate'] as $ids => $value) {
    $stmt->execute([
        $value,
        $ids,
    ]);
}
```

> Is it ok to do massive looping through of MySql queries and if so
>   which loops are best used here? While vs Foreach, For, Do, etc?.

This depends on the data at cause. There's no absolute answer. If you keep your `prepare()` outside of loop and `execute()` inside of them it should be ok. I most of the time use foreach as I rarely have enough data to exceed the memory limit.

> And then what is best here bindParam vs bindValue, placeholders ? vs name etc?

It's a matter of preference. When I have many a fields to be changed in a single query and putting them in the right order is tiresome, I use named placeholders. But I vastly prefer positioned placeholders.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Apologies for slow reply, somehow missed post notification and been busy. Still new here for now, 
Anyway I did get stuck at first.. The square brackets returned an error. 

So inside the foreach I tried:

$stmt->execute(array($allot, $id)); 

But then I also had to change the form name T0:
`code`
<td><input type="text" name="allocate[<?php echo $ID; ?>]"> </td>

From:
<td><input type="text" name="allocate[]"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>"></td>

Off course doing the prepare() outside the loop was the clue. Thanks!

Comment: However this was just One column to update

date - I am wondering what many columns will be like? Nested Foreach loops??? (I hope not) 
eg. UPDATE tablename SET col1 = col1, col2 = col2, col3 = col3 (etc etc) WHERE id = id